Unable to use the ticks-labels attribute defined in the Documentation
What is affected by this bug?
Bar charts, when adding a secondary category-axis. Doesn't seem to follow the documentation (https://salesforcelabs.github.io/LightningWebChartJS/docs/api/axes/cartesian/category.html) as the ticks-labels aren't used?
Where on the platform does it happen?
On a ServiceMax page on the Installed Product, under IB Technical Attribute
How do we replicate the issue?
I have a LWC defined as below, first the html-part
 <c-sample-app-item>
  <c-chart slot="chartExample" type="bar" responsive="true">
    <c-dataset labels='["21;-One","Two","23;-One","Two","24;-One","Two","22-One","Two"]'>
      <c-data label="OK" detail="[17,17,16,16,17,17,16,17]" backgroundcolor='rgba(50, 150, 237, 1)' stack="1" categorypercentage=1></c-data>
      <c-data label="Flagged" detail="[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]" backgroundcolor='rgba(119, 185, 242, 1)' stack="1" categorypercentage=1></c-data>
      <c-data label="NOK" detail="[17,17,17,16,19,18,17,17]" backgroundcolor='rgba(157, 83, 242, 1)' stack="1" categorypercentage=1></c-data>
    </c-dataset>
    <c-cartesian-category-axis 
      axis="x" 
      stacked="true" 
      position="bottom" 
      type="category">
    </c-cartesian-category-axis> 
    <c-cartesian-category-axis 
      axis="x"  
      position="top"
// These aren't visible/used anywhere in the chart visualization as-is, but still pull the labels from the dataset
      ticks-labels='["21","23","24","22"]'
    >
    </c-cartesian-category-axis>  
    <c-cartesian-axis 
      axis="y" 
      stacked="true">
    </c-cartesian-axis>
    <c-title 
      text="Curve controls"></c-title>
    <c-legend 
      position="right"></c-legend>
  </c-chart>
</c-sample-app-item>

Added the js-part as well, although it doesn't impact testing afaik?
import { LightningElement, api ,wire} from 'lwc'; 
import { getRecord, getFieldValue, getFieldDisplayValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import SVMXC__SM_Attr_Value__c from '@salesforce/schema/SVMXC__SM_IB_Technical_Attributes__c.SVMXC__SM_Attr_Value__c';
import SVMXC__SM_Attr_Name__c from '@salesforce/schema/SVMXC__SM_IB_Technical_Attributes__c.SVMXC__SM_Attr_Name__c';



export default class tFBarChart extends LightningElement {
    @api label;
    @api AtDataformatted;
    @api ticksLabels;
    @api recordId;
    @api rendered = false;    

// Record if the view is on a IB_Technical_Attributes object itself
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [SVMXC__SM_Attr_Value__c,SVMXC__SM_Attr_Name__c] }) SVMXC__SM_IB_Technical_Attributes__c;
get ticksLabels(){
  return '["A","B"]';
}   

The output looks like this.

Expected behavior:
The ticks-labels should allow a secondary axis to be included, with defined labels from the script. The end-goal is to remove the "21","23,"24","22" from the data labels of the stacks themselves and instead be grouped in four "overall stacks"
According to documentation (https://salesforcelabs.github.io/LightningWebChartJS/docs/api/axes/cartesian/category.html) the ticks-labels should do the trick, with some adjustments to offset, but currently its just showing the dataset labels for the second axis as well.
The goal is to have it look like this in the end


Added the js defined for the lwc
